# NestJS - pub/sub pattern in microservices

Tags: node.js, amqp, nestjs

Is there a way to use NestJS microservices with the pub/sub pattern? For example with amqp? As far as I understand, every 'microservice type' is following the request / response pattern.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

```
@EventPattern('user_created')
async handleUserCreated(data: Record<string, unknown>) {
  // business logic
}
```

```
async publish() {
  this.client.emit<number>('user_created', new UserCreatedEvent());
}
```

https://docs.nestjs.com/microservices

Answer (score 2):

The above solution does not work.
See here
https://github.com/nestjs/nest/issues/3981

As per the NestJs documentation, you have two options.

1. Either use Redis or NATS as a transporter.
   or
2. Create your own transport https://github.com/nestjs/docs.nestjs.com/issues/113